# Extracting values containing criteria from 1 column

Tags: excel

I have a column

```
Row   |Header  
------+------  
  001 | ABC  
  002 | AC  
  003 | AD  
  004 | BCA  
  005 | DBC
```

The way my sheet works is user types in criteria `*BC*` into one cell.

My VLOOKUP references said cell (with value `*BC*` in it).

Expected Result:

```
ABC
BCA
DBC
```

Actual Result

I understand that VLOOKUP for criteria 'BC' will only return 'ABC'.

I need to absolute reference the cell which the user types in the criteria, but I wish to return a list of values.

How would I go about approaching this? Array formula doesn't work correctly AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

If on has access to the  dynamic array formulas(Currently only available to Office 365 Insiders):

```
=FILTER(B2:B6,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D1,B2:B6)))
```

Put that in the first cell and the rest will fill automatically.

[image]

---

If not then INDEX/AGGREGATE should do it:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($B$2:$B$6)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D$1,B$2:$B$6))),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

Put that in the first cell and copy down till one gets blanks.

[image]

---

one ***LARGE*** Note:  The use of SEARCH makes the use of `*` in the lookup not needed as it will search the string regardless.